# How to make a DejalActivityView over a popover view

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uipopovercontroller, layer

I have a split view controller within a navigation controller and I want to put a DejalActivityView over everything it when I'm doing certain operations. Right now I'm using the following code:

```
 - (void)showActivityView
 {
     UIView *viewToUse = [MSMasterViewController get].splitViewController.navigationController.view;
     [DejalBezelActivityView activityViewForView:viewToUse];
     [DejalActivityView currentActivityView].showNetworkActivityIndicator = YES;
 }
```

This works in landscape mode, but when in portrait mode with the master view in popover form, the dejal activity view appears behind the popover. Is there a better view to use that will cover the whole screen?

[image: ugly screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use your Window as Superview, and only change relativ Frame positing.

greetings Oli

Comment: add this in comment place not in answer place